# Converting a dataset to nominal data

Tags: list-manipulation

Im trying to covert a list of data to nominal data.
Here is the data.

```
list = {{"one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"},
   {"a", "a", "d", "b", "c", "c"},
   {"b", "c", "b", "a", "f", "c"},
   {"b", "f", "b", "g", "a", "b"},
   {"b", "h", "a", "i", "c", "b"},
   {"b", "i", "c", "a", "a", "i"},
   {"a", "c", "k", "a", "a", "a"}
   };
```

Lets say for example i only want to convert the following columns

```
column={1,3,4,6}
```

Lets remove any duplicates from the list

```
titles = Table[
  Sort[DeleteDuplicates[First /@ list[[2 ;;, {column[[i]]}]]]], {i, 
   Length[column]}]
```

Lets convert the titles to nominal data

```
titleReplacement = 
 Table[Table[0 + i, {i, Length[titles[[j]]]}], {j, 
   First@Dimensions[titles]}]
```

Lets now apply the associations

```
Flatten[Table[{titles[[i]] -> titleReplacement[[i]]}, {i, 
   Length[titles]}], 1]
```

This  results in the output.

```
{{"a", "b"} -> {1, 2}, {"a", "b", "c", "d", "k"} -> {1, 2, 3, 4, 
   5}, {"a", "b", "g", "i"} -> {1, 2, 3, 4}, {"a", "b", "c", 
   "i"} -> {1, 2, 3, 4}}
```

The problem im having is that the output is in the wrong format.

I'm trying to achieve this:

````
example = {{"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2}, {"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, 
   "d" -> 4, "k" -> 5}, {"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "g" -> 3, 
   "i" -> 4}, {"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "i" -> 4}}

Thank you for reading.
```
````

Comment: Use `Thread /@ <your last result>`?

Comment: @MarcoB of course, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps more directly:

```
Thread /@ (# -> Range[Length[#]] &) /@ 
  Union /@ Transpose@ list[[2 ;;, column]]

% == example     (* Out: True *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
MapIndexed[# -> #2[[1]] &] /@ Union /@ Transpose[Rest[list]][[column]]
```

> ```
> {{"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2},
>  {"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "d" -> 4,  "k" -> 5}, 
>  {"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "g" -> 3, "i" -> 4}, 
>  {"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "i" -> 4}}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @MarcoB for your suggestion.

Applying Thread/@ works perfectly.

```
Thread /@ 
 Flatten[Table[{titles[[i]] -> titleReplacement[[i]]}, {i, 
    Length[titles]}], 1]

{{"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2}, {"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "d" -> 4, 
  "k" -> 5}, {"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "g" -> 3, "i" -> 4}, {"a" -> 1, 
  "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "i" -> 4}}
```